# Retrieve data in database and display it in calendar control VB.Net-2010 windows form application

Tags: vb.net

I am targeting to create a Scheduling System in VB.Net and I am using Calendar Control, before I will ask my question, Let me explain to you first what scenario I would like to happen.

Here is my form:

[image: I have a form in VB.Net and it looks like this.]

and here is my database:

[image: and here is my database]

How can I display data in my calendar like this?

[image: Now here is my question. How can I display those data in my Calendar Control? like this (Example),how to implement vb.net code]

How can I achieve this kind of output? Regardless of how many data I will input it will Group the Data by Date and display it in the Calendar.

Comment: To get assistance, please post the code for what you have tried along with your actual VB.net code for the calendar.

Comment: Try
            con.Open()
            Dim eventend As String
            eventend = "SELECT bookingname,arrival date FROM BookingDetails Where arrivaldate"
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If rdr.HasRows = True Then
                While rdr.Read
                    

                End While
            End If
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception



        End Try

Comment: how to implement vb.net calendar control,please explain

Comment: Vendetta, you need to update your question to show your code, what you've done, data source and what your problem is. If you have not tried to implement one yet, perhaps check out this link for some documentation on a sample control https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38699/A-Professional-Calendar-Agenda-View-That-You-Will

Comment: Thank you steveB but i want how to implement large type of calendar control view,please help me...